# Spiral problem about simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $S$ be the spiral in the complex plane defined by
 $S=\{te^{it}:0\le t \le \infty\}$ . Prove that $\mathbb C\setminus S$ is simply connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By regarding $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$ as $E=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(\rho \cos\rho,\rho\sin\rho):\rho\geq 0\}$ we may notice that $E$ can be written as a union of the regions $\Gamma_0,\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,\Gamma_3,\ldots,$ where
$$ \Gamma_k=\{(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta):0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi, 2\pi k<\rho<2\pi(k+1)\} $$
and $\Gamma_k\cap\Gamma_{k+1}$ is a segment. $\Gamma_0$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)\times[0,1)$ and $\Gamma_k$ (for $k>0$) is homeomorphic to $(0,1)\times[0,1]$, so for any $k\geq 0$ $\Gamma_k$ is simply connected. By [van Kampen's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem) and induction
$$\bigcup_{k=0}^{N}\Gamma_k$$
is simply connected for any $N\geq 0$ (and homeomorphic to $(0,1)\times(0,N+1]$), hence $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$ is simply connected (and homeomorphic to $(0,1)\times\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a homeomorphism from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$ taking the nonnegative real line to the spiral.

$$
z \mapsto z e^{i|z|}
$$

Now all you have to show is that the complex plane, with the nonnegative real line deleted, is simply connected.

Using the diffeomorphism $z \mapsto (-z)^\frac{1}{2}$ from this deleted plane to the positive half-plane, all you have to show is that the postive (open) half-plane is simply connected.

But it's convex, so that's dead simple.